# Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, package, installation, syntax-error

I am trying to install a R package from zip file using code below:

```
install.packages("M:/packages/predictCRIS.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

I get following error in R

```
    Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'predictCRIS/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Can someone have  try to install/troubleshoot it?

link to the package in google drive:
[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Os2UZhVwAFR015akZOcVE4aUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I guess it is just a typo. Try `install.packages("M:/packages/predictCRIS.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")`with a slash (`/`) after `M:`

Comment: thanks for paying attention @smoff but it was just a typo here! could you install the package successfully ?